# How long does the Google Drive SDK "short lived" download URL exist for?

Tags: url, download, google-drive-api

The reference for downloadUrl states that the link exists for a short amount of time. How long is this roughly? Minutes, hours, days?

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#downloadUrl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not rely on this URL for more than minutes or hours, but in reality it is currently stable for a day or so. This is subject to change, so best to get the URL directly before downloading.

Edit: The difference between this `downloadURL` and the `webContentLink` is that the `webContentLink` uses authorization from the user's browser cookie, the `downloadURL` requires an authorized API request (using OAuth 2.0).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! So why use this rather than webContentLink?

Comment: Updated the question to clarify.