# What is expiration time for downloadUrl in Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does the Google Drive SDK “short lived” download URL exist for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730648/how-long-does-the-google-drive-sdk-short-lived-download-url-exist-for)

In [Google Drive API reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#downloadUrl) it says that downloadUrl contains short lived download URL. How on average this links live?

Few minutes, hours, a day?

Comment: Thx for link to that. Still there is no precise answer how long this link is alive. For example when you query Dropbox API you get direct link which expires after 4 hours and with link there is additional field with expiration time.

Comment: Ok, after some investigation I see that I misunderstood how downloadUrl works. I've created [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568909/does-google-drive-api-support-providing-link-direct-to-a-file-which-is-available) where I have explained it more precisely.