# Does Google Drive API support providing link direct to a file which is available in Dropbox API

Tags: google-drive-api, dropbox-api

If I want to let some thirdparty user to download file directly from some Dropbox account I can ask Dropbox to provide direct link, which **expires after 4 hours** via this [/media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#media) method.

In Google Drive there is [downloadUrl](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#downloadUrl) property but it requires passing accessToken. Is there any other way to make Google Drive behave a little more like Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is the `webContentLink` field in a file that you can pass to a user to download the file in their browser.

Comment: AFAIK webContentLink doesn't expire.