# Failed in getting the downloadUrl property of files in Google Drive with python API

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I want to obtain the direct download link of a certain file on Google Drive and I used **Google API Client for python** and here's a part of my codes, which basically is the copy of the [quickstart example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python):

```
SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
FILE_ID = "xxxxxx"


def get_credentials():
    ...
    return credentials

if __name__ == '__main__':
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build("drive", "v3", http=http)

    web_link = service.files().get(fileId=FILE_ID, fields="webContentLink").execute() # success
    download_link = service.files().get(fileId=FILE_ID, fields="downloadUrl").execute() # throw an error
```

Then I got the 400 error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/xxxxxx?alt=json&fields=downloadUrl returned "Invalid field selection downloadUrl">
```

I searched and read all related questions about this problem. As one said in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730648/how-long-does-the-google-drive-sdk-short-lived-download-url-exist-for/11731117#11731117):

> The difference between this downloadURL and the webContentLink is that
>   the webContentLink uses authorization from the user's browser cookie,
>   the downloadURL requires an authorized API request (using OAuth 2.0).

So I thought maybe I didn't authorize the request successfully. However the first three statements in main part, did it for me according to the [guide](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth):

> Use the authorize() function of the Credentials class to apply
>   necessary credential headers to all requests made by an httplib2.Http
>   instance ... Once an httplib2.Http object has been authorized, it is
>   typically passed to the build function

So what's wrong with my program? And if I want to write my own request with urllib or requests to reproduce the error, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`downloadURL` is a field that is available for File resources in the Google Drive API **version 2** but not **version 3** which you seem to be using.

In Google Drive API v3 the field has been replaced by doing a `files.get` with `?alt=media` request to directly download a file without having to find out the specific URL for it. [You can read more about the differences and changes between API v2 and v3 here.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#fields)

Here is an example of how you can download files using the python Google API client library with Google Drive API v3:

```
file_id = '0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M'
request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print "Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
```

[Check out the official documentation regarding downloading files using the API v3 here for more examples.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads)

Comment: Oh,actually, I want to share the direct download link  to others rather than downloading it. I prefer the direct download link to webContentLink because I think it's more convenient (people can download my file directly just by clicking my shared link). I cannot do it with v3, right? If you have any clue , please tell me. Nevertheless, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Spike if the file is shared publicly the `webContentLink` is the url to download it, without requiring login or authentication. Alternatively there is `webViewLink` for opening files using the Google Drive viewer on file types it supports. Note that `webContentLink` will not require authentication only if the file is shared publicly on the web. If the file is not shared publicly it will require login by a user which has been given access to the file.